# Adding Switch to WHERE clausse

Tags: sql

I've been trying to add a switch into the following script.
If `@IgnoreExclusions = 1` then I do not want to exclude any of the values in `Controltb_AssocAccounts_ExcludedSurnameDOB` or in `Controltb_AssocAccounts_ExcludedDOB` ?

I've included one of my attempts but I don't think this is very readable and also I'm unsure if it works reliably as `NULL` could be a value in one of the exclusion lists.

```
DECLARE @IgnoreExclusions TINYINT = 1;

SELECT  ua.UserAccountKey,          
FROM    #Accounts x 
        INNER JOIN WH.dbo.vw_DimUserAccount ua      
         ON 
         ( --surname and DOB need to match
         x.Surname = ua.Surname AND 
         x.DOB = ua.DOB
         ) 
         AND  
         x.UserAccountKey <> ua.UserAccountKey
WHERE   EXISTS  
          (
          SELECT x.Surname, x.DOB
          EXCEPT
          SELECT ExcludedSurname,ExcludedDOB 
          FROM   WH.dbo.Controltb_AssocAccounts_ExcludedSurnameDOB
          )
        AND
        EXISTS
          (
          SELECT x.DOB
              --SELECT CASE WHEN @IgnoreExclusions = 1 THEN NULL ELSE x.DOB END --<<<<ATTEMPT
          EXCEPT 
          SELECT ExcludedDOB 
          FROM   WH.dbo.Controltb_AssocAccounts_ExcludedDOB
        )   
GROUP BY    ua.UserAccountKey;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what variant of SQL you're using, but couldn't a simple `OR` clause do the trick?

```
DECLARE @IgnoreExclusions TINYINT = 1;

SELECT  ua.UserAccountKey,          
FROM    #Accounts x 
    INNER JOIN WH.dbo.vw_DimUserAccount ua      
        ON x.Surname = ua.Surname
            AND x.DOB = ua.DOB
            AND x.UserAccountKey <> ua.UserAccountKey
WHERE EXISTS  
    (
        SELECT x.Surname, x.DOB
        EXCEPT
        SELECT ExcludedSurname,ExcludedDOB 
        FROM   WH.dbo.Controltb_AssocAccounts_ExcludedSurnameDOB
    )
    AND 
    (
        @IgnoreExclusions = 1 OR EXISTS
        (
              SELECT x.DOB
              EXCEPT 
              SELECT ExcludedDOB 
              FROM   WH.dbo.Controltb_AssocAccounts_ExcludedDOB
        )
    )
GROUP BY ua.UserAccountKey;
```